# What is the packet protocol used for communicating switch configuration changes over the network?

Tags: switch, wireshark

I am trying to isolate the packets used to communicate a switch's configuration changes. More specifically, whenever  I use the online tool on my laptop and configure the switch (and hit save) I want to be able to see the packets that have been sent to the switch in order to envoke this change.

In my tests using Wireshark I have found that only UDP packets had been sent from laptop to switch.

Is this normal? I would have thought this process used a connection orientated protocol.

Comment: Without knowing what kind of switch or online tool, we can't say for sure.  Please edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: SNMP (simple network management protocol) uses udp ports 161 and 162 by default.  But that’s just a guess because you did not include your wireshark data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I manage a switch. I use ssh or older switches telnet. And else http or https. But this is very basic. SNMP is also possible.